# Default Browser Prompt

Tags: browser, windows-7

I want to open some links in IE and some in Chrome (Windows 7). My idea would be to set my default "browser" to a simple (hopefully free) application which has a dialogue which asks me in which browser I want to open a http:// link. Has anyone found/made such a utility already?

Answer (score 0):

No takers so I rolled my own - introducing [OptiBrowser](https://github.com/cawoodm/optibrowser) - BOOM!